# How to discard changes in PreferenceActivity if users press R.id.home or back button?

Tags: android

I want that any change made in PreferenceActivity won't be saved unless the user press the "Done" Button that I have added to ActionBar, so, if back button is pressed, changes won't apply and switches will change back to their previous values.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

According to @Ravindra Kushwaha suggestion, I elaborated the following code:

```
boolean push_switch, push_on, push_off, push_stats;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    push_switch = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_switch", true);
    push_on = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_on", true);
    push_off = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_off", true);
    push_stats = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_stats", true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id)
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case 1000: // Done button
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("push_switch", push_switch);
    editor.putBoolean("push_on", push_on);
    editor.putBoolean("push_off", push_off);
    editor.putBoolean("push_stats", push_stats);
    editor.apply();
    finish();
}
```

which seem to work as expected and meets my expectations, but...

Is it the proper way to do it or is it not recommended in any aspect? I found it weird... letting android to apply changes by itself and reverting them manually if back if pressed, applying again the previous one...

I think it would be easier if I am the one who applies changes **only** if done is pressed.

Comment: I have no clue about what to try... The switches values seem to be stored in app config in the right moment that I switch them.

Comment: Its logic bro...You have to maintain the five variable which consists the value like they are clicked or not...On done button click you have to get the value from these 5 variables and save it to yours shared prefernce ...Got it dost

Comment: Really? I had that in mind, but I though that there would be a preference or something in SDK to just revert changes if back button is pressed, I mean, back button = cancel changes... alright, so I have to do it manually, right?

Comment: Yes bro...Try it...If u get any concern than plz let me know

Comment: well, I'm missing the equivalent of getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) to write instead of read

Comment: Ok, I found it, I have to get the editor, and commit changes

Comment: thanks, question update, please, check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to get the valUe of the toggles in your `onCreate` that IS, what was the previous state of the `toggle` either , it was off or on , like below:-

```
boolean push_switch, push_on, push_off, push_stats;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    push_switch = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_switch", true);
    push_on = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_on", true);
    push_off = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_off", true);
    push_stats = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("push_stats", true);

 ////And than after , you have to set these values in yours toggle like:
   toggleFirst.setChecked(push_on)
   toggleSecond.setChecked(push_off)
   toggleThird.setChecked(push_switch)
   toggleForth.setChecked(push_stats)

}

  /////Perfom click listeners in yours all toogle like below and save the value in the boolean variables
YOUR_TOGGLE_BUTTONS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
    {
        push_on = true;   ///// i am assign all value together , you have to maintain setOnCheckedChangeListener for each toggle and assign the vale..for the example ,i have done these
        push_off= true;
        push_switch= true;
        push_stats= true;

    }
    else
    {
        push_on = false;
        push_off= false;
        push_switch= false;
        push_stats= false;

    }

}
});
  //////And in the last on Done button click listener save your data like below

 YOUR_DONE_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /////HERE SAVE THE VALUE INSIDE THE SHARED PREFRENCE..
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a flag for "Done" Button. 
When you enter preference activity save all the values in preference as default .
if user click "Done" change them accordingly otherwise change values to preference.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean... question updated, I already got what I wanted, but done button just finishes activity since android already applies the changes by itself :/ I would like to disable this behaviour